# Webtoon/Webcomic where a vampire saves two people who crash their car into a lake

Tags: story-identification, vampire, webcomics

It’s night time and this vampire-ish dude finds two people who crashed their car into a lake. The vampire dude had walked into the lake to the car and pulled the victims out and we later see one of the victims with their head shaved. Then we see one of them wake up, lead out to a little medieval market/village area. Then the victim is given a nice medieval renaissance outfit at one of the stalls.

Comment: When you _"vampire-ish dude"_, do you mean that he was an actual vampire, or that he just resembled a vampire? Did he have any powers?

Comment: He was very pale, not literally as white as a sheet but his skin color was really fair. His hair was ash-blondish or very blond. He had a black vest, a white shirt, a tie, and black pants. He was covered in freckles. That’s all I remember. And I remember reading it on Webtoon.

Comment: He also had a butler or a servant by his side that didn’t like him going outside for some reason. That butler was by his side when he went into the lake, and when he went into the room where the survivor was to see how they were doing.

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this? From what you've described so far, it doesn't sound like there are, and if that's the case, then this question is off-topic here.